# Как правильно описать execvp для Lua FFI?

Tags: lua, exec, ffi

Как правильно описать execvp для Lua FFI? Варианты, которые пробовал:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
int execvp(char * pathname, char * argv[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef"int execvp(const char*file, const char**argv);"
local arg = ffi.new("const char*[3]", {"ls", "-l"})
ffi.C.execvp(arg[0], arg)
```